# HAP parses formatting in HTML documents

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I'm pulling a node from my HTML document using the following code:

```
var nodeCollection = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(@"/html[1]/body[1]/div[2]");
```

The HTML document is formatted with some basic formatting to increase readability with Notepad++. HAP appears to be parsing this formatting (a new line and some tab indents) and returning them in the `innerHTML` and `innerText` properties of a returned HTMLNode:
[image]

Can I mitigate this without altering the input file?

Comment: Have you tried `.Trim()` or did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer This won't necessarily help, because I need to add to the HTML and then re-insert it into the document. Without mitigating this current parsing issue, the content of the node might be altered in such a way as to change the appearance of the final document in a manner not consistent with the desired result - especially if I need to alter properties of nodes rather than just the text within them.

Comment: What have you tried so far? I'd just parse all leading and trailing whitespace characters manually, store them in a pair of strings, make whatever changes are required and add them back to the modified string.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer To be honest, I thought it was a bug with HAP. Am I assuming correctly in that HAP parses the text content of a file and then simply extracts HTML elements from it?

Comment: I don't know what your HTML actually looks like, but if the tabs and line breaks are exactly as you get them, it's hardly HAP's fault. A parser is not supposed to modify whatever it is reading and it has no way of knowing what the whitespaces are used for. So in short - it's not a bug, it's a feature. If you made the HTML yourself I'd recommend **not** adding unwanted whitespaces inside of the html tags you plan on parsing.

Comment: *"Am I assuming correctly in that HAP parses the text content of a file and then simply extracts HTML elements from it?"* It's more like an XML parser but less strict when it comes to opening and closing tags. [Actual method used to load a document](https://github.com/zzzprojects/html-agility-pack/blob/master/src/HtmlAgilityPack.Shared/HtmlDocument.cs#L623) and [this one is used to parse it](https://github.com/zzzprojects/html-agility-pack/blob/master/src/HtmlAgilityPack.Shared/HtmlDocument.cs#L1180).

Comment: It looks like 'iswhitespace' isn't returning true for whatever reason. Having said that, the HTML document I've created follows the same convention as every other HTML document I've ever made, so my assumption is that it is something to do with the way Notepad++ handles tabular indents and carriage returns/new lines. The only other time I've seen this kind of bug is when I've used text files across windows and linux, where windows saves return lines in a format that linux does not recognise. I wonder if this is a similar issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Html Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/)

### innerHtml

innerHtml do what it should do. It show HTML including all HTML tag, space, tab, and new line.

So for this one, it works as expected.

### innerText

For tag such `DIV`, it should **NOT** show space, tab, or new line.

So for innerText, there is a bug.

I have added this request to our roadmap and hope to provide a fix by next Monday. I will edit this answer when it is available.

**EDIT:** Adding Release Notification

Since the v1.6.2, the `InnerText` attribute has been improved to remove line break, space and tab. There is some more improvement that will come in future version to better handle some style attribute that can also affect the `InnerText`

However, the new `InnerText` logic is only available when turning the BackwardCompatibility to false since this change have a to much huge impact on people that currently use this library: `new HtmlDocument() { BackwardCompatibility = false};`